# Correlation on free and paid clients

Tags: correlation, marketing

I have data from a shop and I try to find some valuable info on them. The data contains 3 fields per month for several years. One is the total number of clients, one is the number of clients that pay a subscription and the other, the number of users that had subscription but didn't renew it.

In the meantime, the owner of the shop has made a few changes on the prices of the subscription and I want to study if there was any direct impact on the subscriptions.

Thus, the first thing I did was to create a line graph and a scatterplot, but there wasn't any visible impact. Then, I applied a correlation test on them and the results are:

Total clients - Total clients with subscription: 0.9000349978

Total clients - Not renewals: -0.07161495051

The first one leads that there is a correlation between the number of the paid subscription and the clients. This makes sense. The more clients, the more subscriptions I will have. However, the second one, leads to no correlation on the renewals and the total number of clients.

Is it safe to assume that the changes were successful? Or there are more things that I could check?

Comment: Renewal rates over time would likely be a helpful metric. For example, taking the number of paid subscriptions divided by the total number of clients in January 2014, in February 2014, etc. If you see changes in renewal rates over time, that would likely warrant further investigation!

Comment: There are several changes on the rate close the the price changes, but it seems that everytime the number stablized to a certain percentage (+-3%)